# Can't boot Ubuntu 18.04.1 direct disk on Linode

Tags: linode, kernel-panic, ubuntu-18.04, vfs

I get a kernel panic stating that root cannot be mounted if I boot my Direct Disk installation of Ubuntu 18.04.1 in paravirtualization mode, as seen in this screenshot from the Glish terminal:
[image]

Any idea why I can't boot?  Kernel module?  GRUB settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a recent update, I am now back on paravirtual mode, so this question can now be closed.  It might have been a bug in the Ubuntu distribution that caused the issue.

Comment: You can delete the question, or, if you think it should stay around, mark this as answer as the accepted answer. Please don't just leave it hanging, though.

Comment: Done!  I think I will leave it in case someone panics due to installing an outdated 18.04 image on their Linode.